# What is the meaning of "to walk on stormy seas", in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "to walk on stormy seas", in the following sentence,

> You raise me up, so I can stand on mountains
>
> You raise me up, **to walk on stormy seas**
>
> I am strong, when I am on your shoulders
>
> You raise me up, **to** more than I can be

?

Does it mean "You raise me up, so I can walk on stormy seas"? 
or does it mean "You raise me up, and you will walk on stormy seas" ?

Does "to more than I can be" mean " You raise me up, so I will be more than I can be"? or does "to more than I can be" mean "You raise me up, because you want more than I can be" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"stormy seas" is used to refer to difficult situation or difficult times.

"**walk** on stormy seas" is a difficult situation made easy (as easy as walking).

So the meaning of the line is: as a consequence of you raising me, I can face difficult situation with ease.

Comment: if so, does "to" in the sentence mean "as a consequence, so I can" ?

Comment: it is more like: "in order to"

Comment: if so, does "You raise me up, to walk on stormy seas" mean "You raise me up in order to walk on stormy seas"?(=>Who walk on stormy seas? You or I ? According to a grammar, I can not be sure that the interpretation should be " You raise me up for me to walk on stormy seas.". I have thought that the interpretation may be "You raise me up (for you) to walk on stormy seas". Now, because I know I am wrong, I want to know what I am misunderstanding grammatically. What am i misunderstanding grammatically ?

Comment: I am not entirely sure about the original intention, but "You" is probably God, who is helping "me" throughout life: stand on mountains, walk stormy seas, become more than I can be.